# Can one express the power relation $a=b^m$ as a set of polynomial conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

In the famous 1976 paper *Diophantine representation of the set of prime numbers* in the Monthly by Jones-Sato-Wada-Wiens, the exponentional relation $f=k!$ (stating that some integer $f$ is exactly a factorial of a smaller integer $k$) is shown to be the equivalent to the existence of 8 integers $j, h, n, p, q, w, z, o$ satisfying the conditions:

(I) $q=wz+h+j$

(II) $z=f(h+j)+h$

(III) $(2k)^3(2k+2)(n+1)^2+1=o^2$

(IV) $p=(n+1)^k$

(V) $q=(p+1)^n$

(VI) $z=p^{k+1}$

These are still in general power form (exponential, if you like), and they next have a theorem 2.12 that converts the system (I)-(VI) into a larger one of polynomial conditions that have fixed degrees (all less than 26).

**Question:** can one express the power relation $a=b^m$ (stating that some integer $a$ is exactly an $m$-power of a smaller integer $b$) as a set of equivalent polynomial conditions of fixed degree ? **If so, what is that set of conditions ?**

It seems from their paper that it should be possible : i.e. **a set of polynomial conditions like in their theorem 2.12, with only fixed degrees** (I've been unable to extract it).

Many thanks, any comment appreciated!

**Edit:** a +50 bounty added today (sunday 7th) for a solution, or, failing that, a reasonable try...

Comment: Since $b^m$ can be expressed in terms of binomial coefficients, which can in turn be expressed in terms of factorials, this should be possible.

Comment: This is true by Matiyasevich's theorem. I do *not* expect an explicit construction to be simple (and certainly algebra-precalculus is not the correct tag!). See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66511/why-can-diophantine-equations-represent-exponential-growth

Comment: Many thanks for the link. It is surprising that this is so difficult and not yet worked out, yet I'd still like to think that the passage from system (I)-(VI) to theorem 2.12 contains most of what is needed. As for the tag, since the problem does not involve any calculus nor algebra like lots of group theory I was reluctant to use those.